# Splice deleting first items from array of objects instead of index

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to exclude items from an array of objects based on an array with the indexes I have to remove, but instead it's removing the first items from the array of objects.

My code:

```js
let historicPrecipitation = [{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"1","year":"2014","value":"228.5"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"2","year":"2014","value":"144.7"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"3","year":"2014","value":"120.3"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"4","year":"2014","value":"146.9"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"5","year":"2014","value":"146.4"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"6","year":"2014","value":"128.1"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"7","year":"2014","value":"139.2"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"8","year":"2014","value":"150.0"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"9","year":"2014","value":"199.7"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"10","year":"2014","value":"268.4"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"11","year":"2014","value":"98.5"},{"indicator":"Historic Precipitation","month":"12","year":"2014","value":"139.9"}];

let monthsWithoutRegistration = [4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < monthsWithoutRegistration.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < historicPrecipitation.length; j++) {
        if (parseInt(historicPrecipitation[j]['month']) === parseInt(monthsWithoutRegistration[i])) {
            historicPrecipitation.splice(historicPrecipitation[j], 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(historicPrecipitation);
```

Comment: You could instead do this with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), instead of the nested for loops

Comment: There isn't any JSON in this question. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of a data structure (that can be an object or an array or something else, a number for example). In order to manipulate the encoded data, the JSON needs to be parsed. The result of parsing is a data structure similar to the one used to generate the JSON. There is no JSON, no JSON parsing or JSON generation in this question. `historicPrecipitation` is an array of objects.

Comment: @axiac - Yes there is, it's an array of JSON objects.

Comment: @Lissy93: As axiac says, it is an array of *objects*; JSON (as the N for *Notation*  indicates) is a way of *representing* objects using text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `j` instead of `historicPrecipitation[j]` in `splice` because you should pass `index` not `object`:

```js
let historicPrecipitation = [{
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "1",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "228.5"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "2",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "144.7"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "3",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "120.3"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "4",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "146.9"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "5",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "146.4"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "6",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "128.1"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "7",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "139.2"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "8",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "150.0"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "9",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "199.7"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "10",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "268.4"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "11",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "98.5"
}, {
  "indicator": "Historic Precipitation",
  "month": "12",
  "year": "2014",
  "value": "139.9"
}];

let monthsWithoutRegistration = [4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < monthsWithoutRegistration.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < historicPrecipitation.length; j++) {
    if (parseInt(historicPrecipitation[j]['month']) === parseInt(monthsWithoutRegistration[i])) {
      historicPrecipitation.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(historicPrecipitation);
```

Answer (score 0):

The splice syntax is wrong,

replace with this

```
  historicPrecipitation.splice(j, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `filter` instead of the nested for loops:

```js
let filteredHistoricPrecipitation = historicPrecipitation.filter(x => 
    !monthsWithoutRegistration.includes(parseInt(x['month']))
);
```